# how to use recursion to nest dictionaries while integrating with existing records

Tags: python, json, dictionary, recursion, openstreetmap

I am parsing some XML data from Open Street Map into JSON (later to be uploaded into a database). It is large, so I am using iterparse. I have some tags that look like this

```
<tag 'k'=stringA:stringB:stringC 'v'=value>
```

which I want to parse into

```
{stringA: {stringB: {stringC: value} } }
```

I have done so with an ugly hardcode. However, I would like to create a function that uses recursion to address the same issue in case the 'k' attribute value contains arbitrarily as many ':'.

I created this

```
def nestify(l):
    """Takes a list l and returns nested dictionaries where each element from
    the list is both a key to the inner dictionary and a value to the outer, 
    except for the last element of the list, one which is only a value.
    For best understanding, feed w = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'v'] to the
    function and look at the output."""
    n = len(l)
    if n==2:
        key = l[0]
        value = l[1]
    else:
        key = l[0]
        value = nestify(l[1:])

    return {key:value}
```

which works. (You have to make the keys and value into a list first.) Except not really, because it always makes a new dictionary. I need it to respect the previous data and integrate. For example, if my parser encounters

```
<tag 'k'=a:b:c 'v'=1 />
```

and then in the same element

```
<tag 'k'=a:d:e 'v'=2 />
```

I need it to make

```
{a: {'b': {'c' : 1}, 'd' : {'e' : 2}}}
```

and not

```
{a: {'b' : {'c' : 1}}}

{a: {'d' : {'e' : 2}}}
```

I have tried this code:

```
def smart_nestify(l, record):
n = len(l)
if n==2:
    key = l[0]
    value = l[1]
else:
    key = l[0]
    value = smart_nestify(l[1:], key)
if key not in record:
    return {key:value}                   
else:
    record[key] = value
    return record
```

but it still writes over and returns only the latest record. Why is that? How can I fix this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a "smarter" nestify that merges a list `l` into the dictionary `record`:

```
def smarter_nestify(l, record):
    if len(l) == 2:
        return {l[0]: l[1]}
    key = l.pop(0)
    record[key] = smarter_nestify(l, record.get(key, {}))
    return record
```

Each time through the recursion, it pops the first element from the list `l.pop(0)` and merges the value from the next level of the dictionary `record.get(key, {})`.

You can call it with two lists like this:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 1]
record = smarter_nestify(l, {})

l = ['a', 'd', 'e', 2]
record = smarter_nestify(l, record)
print record
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it is better to just use iteration rather than recursion.  Here’s the iterative answer.

```
g_values = dict()
def make_nested(l):
    """
    l is the array like you have for nestify
    e.g., ['a',  'b', 'c', 1 ] or ['a', 'd', 'e', 2]
    """
    global g_values
    value = l[-1] ; l = l[:-1]
    last_dict = None
    for x in l[:-1]:
        mp_temp = last_dict if last_dict is not None or g_values
        last_dict = mp_temp.get(x)
        if last_dict is None:
            mp_temp[x] = dict()
            last_dict = mp_temp[x]
    last_dict[l[-1]] = value
```

While I didn’t test it, you could also try something like this recursively:

```
def make_nested(values, l):
    if len(l == 2):
        values[l[0]] = l[1]
        return
    mp = values.get(l[0])
    if mp is None:
        values[l[0]] = dict()
        make_nested(values[l[0]], l[1:])
    else:
        make_nested(mp, l[1:])
```

Comment: I had an iterative solution, I was looking for the recursive.